# Can one meet criteria, or satisfy requirements?

Tags: word-choice

I usually see 'satisfy the criteria' and 'meet the requirements', but is it acceptable to use 'meet the criteria', or 'satisfy the requirements'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*The Oxford Collocations Dictionary* says the following:

**VERB+criterion:** fit, fulfill, meet, satisfy. *The Macmillan Collocations Dictionary* gives one more verb, "match".

**VERB+requirement:** comply with, fit, fulfill, match, meet, satisfy, suit. *The Macmillan Collocations Dictionary* gives three more verbs, "achieve", "adhere to", "conform to".

Comment: I was unaware of that resource. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I see no problem with using either of the proposed phases. In fact, I think I almost prefer *meet the criteria* and *satisfy the requirements*.

Answer (score 6):

[Google NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=satisfy+the+requirements%2C+meet+the+criteria&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=0&smoothing=3) says that both those phrases are in common use, so I guess the answer is yes.

[image]

Comment: True, but "meet" seems to be the more common word for both [criteria](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meet%20the%20criteria%2Csatisfy%20the%20criteria&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and [requirements](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meet%20the%20requirements%2Csatisfy%20the%20requirements&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 1):

I would add the four options mentioned at the question to compare also the frequency of the expressions, not only if they exist. Google Ngram Viewer is a great resource :)
[image: ngram viewer plot]