# Single word that can be used for "Living up to"?

Tags: single-word-requests

While preparing a writeup, I went through this small problem. I want to make it short, and writing the whole phrase is making it look like a 'big' sentence.
Is there a possibility of using a single word for "Living up to"?
For example:

___ the expectations

___ the requirements

or something similar.

Answer (score 7):

Also, consider [**fulfill**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fulfill):

> 2. b :  to meet the requirements of (a business order)

- To fulfill the requirements.
- To fulfill the expectations.

There are some other words in [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67349/can-one-meet-criteria-or-satisfy-requirements), such as "satisfy the criteria", that could apply to your case.

Comment: I think "fulfill" best fits the sense of "live up to". In contrast, "meeting" requirements or expectations may mean doing just well enough to get by.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the fact "to fulfill" is described as "to meet" kinda tricked me. I'll delete it and leave it up to the OP to decide which he/she likes better.

Comment: Yes, fulfill suits best. but I was looking for something which sounds a bit different and unique. I want to make my statement look even more stronger.

Answer (score 4):

- to meet the expectations
- to meet the requirements

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [**satisfy**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/satisfy) which means:

> Adequately meet or comply with (a condition, obligation, or demand)

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

**To satisfy the requirement(s)** is more idiomatic than **to satisfy the expectation(s)** and the [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=satisfied+the+requirements%2Cmet+the+requirements%2Cfulfilled+the+requirements%2C+satisfied+the+requirement%2Cmet+the+requirement%2Cfulfilled+the+requirement&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csatisfied%20the%20requirements%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmet%20the%20requirements%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfulfilled%20the%20requirements%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csatisfied%20the%20requirement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmet%20the%20requirement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfulfilled%20the%20requirement%3B%2Cc0) shows the former is more broadly used than **to fulfill the requirement(s)**.

In terms of expectation(s), the [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=met+the+expectation%2C+met+the+expectations%2C+satisfied+the+expectation%2C+satisfied+the+expectations%2C+fulfilled+the+expectation%2C+fulfilled+the+expectations&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmet%20the%20expectation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmet%20the%20expectations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csatisfied%20the%20expectation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csatisfied%20the%20expectations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfulfilled%20the%20expectation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfulfilled%20the%20expectations%3B%2Cc0) shows **to meet** and **to fulfill** are more broadly used than **to satisfy**.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps 'achieved', especially if you change the rest of it to 'the objectives'

Answer (score 1):

- reach ( living up to - goes for getting somewhere you desire and you want to get)